# Minimialist Site: Header flexbox text vertically centered on Chrome desktop, but not Chrome mobile. Why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niramit' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="bar">
            <div id="title" class="header-text">title</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uey85nbj/

Chrome Desktop: 27 pixels above and 29 pixels below

[image]

Chrome Mobile: 40 pixels above and 31 pixels below

[image]

Comment: Can you change the font and check, it looks like font is having some kind of extra padding in top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Akhil Aravind suggested, it appears the font is the issue.  Here is the image without the special font.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you put a background-color on the div that contains your text, you'll get a sense of what's happening (and this is what it looks like on Firefox and Chrome desktops for me, so I don't know how you got your first screenshot):

[image: green background on text showing how the text element is framed in its parent]

That div is very well-centered vertically, but because your text is in all lowercase, the optical alignment is off. Fonts don't always take up space in the manner you expect, in part because most of the characters in a font don't take up all of the space above and below. How the text interacts with the space will change from font to font. Change 'title' to "TITLE" and see how it looks.

Fiddling with the line-height can help you here, or you could do `position: relative; top: -2px`, or `transform: translateY(-2px)` or whatever it is would be most helpful.

I'd recommend getting away from mm as a unit too; pixels, ems/rems, percents, and viewport units better represent how things are measured in a page.

Comment: If that is the correct behavior, why then do we think it is different on different browsers?

Comment: Not sure. Like I said, your screenshot for Chrome for mobile is what I see on Chrome on desktop and Firefox on desktop, so  I was unable to reproduce your test case. The only thing I could think of was maybe it had something to do with the `mm` units.